# Android Studio 0.8.10 resource issues

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, android-studio

I'm experiencing issues with the latest Android Studio update to 0.8.10. I opened my existing project and now all code references to my resources (values, dimens, images, etc) are not properly linked any more. See the example below.

## Example

[image: Android studio example of problem]

## Steps i've tried so far

- Build > Rebuilt Project
- Build > Clean Project
- Restarting Android Studio
- Re-importing the project
- Sync Project with Gradle

Im looking to see if anyone else has had these issues and if there is a possible workaround / fix.

Comment: It would be better to ask on android developer tools g+ page or create issue in their issues tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like updating to the latest `Canary` build (0.8.11) fixes these issues. Also updating to the latest android gradle plugin (0.12) helped too.